# Rust inheritance: call parent method

Tags: inheritance, rust

How can I call a "parent method" in Rust? Like this in Java：

```java
public class parent{
    ...
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Parent method");
    }
}
public class child extends parent{
    ...
    public void doSomething(){
        super.doSomething();
        System.out.println("Child method.");
    }
}
```

In Go, we can simulate it by anonymous fields in struct:

```golang
type parent struct{}

func (self *parent) doSomething() {
    fmt.Println("parent method")
}

type child struct {
    parent
}

func (self *child) doSomething() {
    self.parent.doSomething()
    fmt.Println("child method")
}
func main() {
    var c1 child
    c1.doSomething()
}
```

How to simulate it in Rust?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not quite the same under the hood, but something like

```
trait DoThings {
    fn do_something(&self); 
}

struct Parent;

impl DoThings for Parent {
    fn do_something(&self) { println("doing something"); }
}

struct Child {
    parent: Parent
}

impl DoThings for Child {
    fn do_something(&self) { 
        self.parent.do_something();
        println("child");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Child { parent: Parent };
    c.do_something();
}
```

There are a few proposals for making parts of this automatic (e.g. if we wanted to just call the parent's method directly, i.e. don't override the method in the child, then currently one has to explicitly call the parent's method oneself).

Comment: Is this still the way to do it or have their been updates? Sorry, I have Googled myself but it's hard to find up to date information for Rust.

Comment: @JeroenBollen, yes, still the way to do it.

Comment: The problem with this is that it won't work for Struct fields. For example, what if you want to re-use a base Struct field in some other Structs? `struct Animal { health: int; } struct Dog { fn bark() -> () {...} }` how does Dog inherit Animal's health?

Answer (score -1):

The point of inheritance is being able to overwrite an inherited method. The samples provided above still deal with delegation and not with inheritance.

Let's have a look at some Go code to illustrate this:

```
type Base struct {}
func (Base) Magic() { fmt.Print("base magic") }
func (self Base) MoreMagic() {
  self.Magic()
}

type Foo struct {
  Base
}

func (Foo) Magic() { fmt.Print("foo magic") }
```

If you run the code above this way

```
f := new(Foo)
f.Magic()
```

it will print "foo magic" to the console and not "base magic". However, if we run this code

```
f := new(Foo)
f.MoreMagic()
```

it will not print "foo magic" as well, but this time "base magic". This is because of the lack of inheritance and thus not being able to overwrite method Magic (aka dynamic linking). So we are still dealing with delegation.

You can work around this f.ex. as described in the section "Inner Patern" in [this](http://objectscape.blogspot.de/2013/09/mimicking-method-overloading-in-go.html) article. I don't know exactly about this concerning Rust. At first sight it seems to be the same.

Comment: Note that this "lack of inheritance" is also a freedom from inheritance and is actually one of the main points of the delegation based object model that Go uses.